# WSO2 Identity Server Get role permissions

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm loading user claims using org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreManager. In the claim information i have the list of roles for the current user. Is there a way to programatically get the assigned permissions for each role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UserAdmin service has a method getRolePermissions that does exactly this.